# How do I distinguish between data structures and abstract data types?

Tags: c++, data-structures, computer-science, abstract-data-type

The following definitions from *Abstract Data Types* (1996) by Dale and Walker:

> **Data Structures**: the implementation of structured relationships.
>
> **ADTs (abstract data types)**: classes of objects whose logical behavior is
>   defined by a set of values and set of operations.

So, let's take a simple class in C++:

```
class Simple {
public:
        void some_simple_action();

private:
        int x, y;
};
```

Simple must be a data structure since it is an implementation, correct? With respect to this class, what is it's abstract data type?

Secondly, am I correct to surmise that ADTs are just a conceptual representation of something: as in the idea of something by which we can call by name? For example, there is a common idea or even formal/logical concept of what a stack is. If I implement a stack in a given programming language, then that which I wrote is now a data structure (of this abstract data type).

Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: "*Simple must be a data structure since it is an implementation, correct?*" An implementation of what? What is the structured relationship at play here?

Comment: If you're familiar with the concept of an interface in OO programming, then roughly speaking an ADT is like an interface and a data structure is like a non-abstract class. A data structure is defined by its internal implementation details, but an ADT is defined by what operations it supports and what their inputs/outputs ought to be.

Comment: Say for example you were simulating a farm. You would create an Animal class which you would create children classes for Sheep, Cow, Pig, etc... You could add a Pig to the farm but probably not an Animal, you know? So in that sense, the Animal stands as a class that wouldn't get instantiated directly, hence it would be abstract.

Comment: Also, take with a grain of salt C++ terminology from a quarter-century ago -- things have come a long way since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part - you are thinking right.

At a high level, concrete Data Type is a *concept* that lets you manufacture instances (called objects in OO)

An ADT (aka Interface) is a *contract*. It does not imply implementation.

WRT your Simple class, ADT would be smth like:

```
class ISimple {
public:
        void some_simple_action() = 0;
};
```

And if you derive "Simple" class from it, you'd be able to inject it wherever the contract requires ISimple.

Comment: Is the keyword virtual missing here?